How do I transpile Angular 17 ES6 app to ES5 for Android 10 devices
Working on a web app for a specialized device that runs Android 10 (Webview uses Chromium <80). When I try to serve the app and test on the Android device, I get errors for using optional chaining and null coalescing.
From my research, the target field on the tsconfig.json gets overwritten by the Angular CLI and these syntax's are non-polyfillable.
Can I configure my Angular.json to run a babel script to convert all the compiled JS into ES5 interpret-able JS after the build process? And I assume, if I could, then this would also get ran when running ng serve?
We are unsure if upgrading WebView on the device or installing Android 11 will break the other essential applications pre installed on the device.
I tried setting target to "es5"/"es2015". This no longer works in Angular 17.
I tried adding 'core-js' to the polyfills. The optional chaining syntax is not polyfillable.

You can always add a command in package.json that will be run so to compile to android like this:
npm run build-android

and in your package.json:
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build-android": "ng build && <your script>"
  },

